# Quarkus: use terraform output in application.yml

Tags: terraform, jvm, quarkus, reactive

I have problems to get terraform output into my application.yml.

The terraform-output is defined like this:

```
output "my_service_aurora_db_application_password" {
  value = data.terraform_remote_state.service-aurora-db.outputs.db_my_service_application_password
  sensitive = true
}
```

I have verified correctness with 'terraform show' - it's populated properly.

Then in my application.yml I try to access it like this:

```
quarkus:
    datasource:
        db-kind: postgresql
        password: ${my.service.aurora.db.application.password}
```

But the container (k8s) is not starting with the following error:

***Could not expand value my.service.aurora.db.application.password in property quarkus.datasource.password***

These are my dependencies:

```
dependencies  {
    implementation enforcedPlatform("io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-bom:${quarkusVersion}")
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-jackson'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-logging-sentry'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-micrometer'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-config-yaml'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-health'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-jwt'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-jwt-build'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-container-image-jib'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-kotlin'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client-reactive'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-fault-tolerance'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-cache'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
    implementation 'io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:2.1.21'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-flyway'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-postgresql'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-redis-client'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-reactive-pg-client'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson'
    testImplementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'
    testImplementation 'io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:3.4.2'
    testImplementation 'io.mockk:mockk:1.12.4'
    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured:5.0.1'
    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:kotlin-extensions:5.0.1'
    testImplementation 'com.willowtreeapps.assertk:assertk:0.25'
    testImplementation 'org.awaitility:awaitility:4.2.0'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.17.1'
}
```

Comment: What happens if you use underscores, i.e., `password: ${my_service_aurora_db_application_password}`?

Comment: the same unfortunately..

Comment: What's the connection between the output and the YML file?

Comment: The output fetches data from a remote terraform state (db-user, password, schema, ...). The Quarkus service needs those to establish the (reactive) database connection. Running terraform show in the Quarkus service shows that the remote state is accessed correctly. I just can't get the values it into Quarkus.

Comment: Is there bash where Qarkus is? I have no idea, hence my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's solved: The service I was working on has a shell script that's parsing the terraform output during deployment to set the correct environment variables. This script was ignoring only the sensitive fields in the outputs json.